# Is there an Excel formula that can provide cell position based on change from TRUE to FALSE?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

all:
I am trying to create an excel formula that find the titration point of a string of true and false statements (shown as 1s and 0s). I cant figure out how to use INDEX MATCH to find the column where the cell values change.

Here is a visual example:

```
Column   1    2    3    4    5    6
Answers  0    0    0    1    1    1 ----> I want the formula to show the average of "3" and "4" (=3.5)
         0    0    0    0    1    1 ----> I want the formula to show the average of "4" and "5" (=4.5)
```

Some notes: all column headers are numbers, so finding the average should be possible. Also, some rows may start with "1" and then transition to "0".

Any advice or help will be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If the numbers are sequential and match the column number then:

```
=MATCH(1,A2:F2,0)-0.5
```

If they they don't:

```
=AVERAGE(INDEX(A$1:F$1,MATCH(1,A2:F2,0)-1),INDEX(A$1:F$1,MATCH(1,A2:F2,0)))
```